# How to run a line of code multiple based on input?

Tags: python, sum, dice

Using Python, I am trying to find a quicker way to run a randint multiple times based on an input without having to write out every single input possibility. This is for a dice roller for tabletop games. Code below

```
import random
from random import randint

i1=input("what type of die?: ")
i2=input("how many times?:")

roll_again = "yes"
while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    
    if i1=="d6":
        if i2=="1":
            value1=randint(1,6)
            print(value1)
            roll_again = input("roll again?")
        if i2=="2":
            value1=randint(1,6)
            value2=randint(1,6)
            print(value1,value2)
            roll_again = input("roll again?")
        if i2=="3":
            value1=randint(1,6)
            value2=randint(1,6)
            value3=randint(1,6)
            print(value1,value2,value3)
            roll_again = input("roll again?")
        if i2=="4":
            value1=randint(1,6)
            value2=randint(1,6)
            value3=randint(1,6)
            value4=randint(1,6)
            print(value1,value2,value3,value4)
            roll_again = input("roll again?")
    
    elif i1=="d4":
        if i2=="1":
            value1=randint(1,4)
            print(value1)
            roll_again = input("roll again?")
        if i2=="2":
            value1=randint(1,4)
            value2=randint(1,4)
            print(value1,value2)
            roll_again = input("roll again?")
        if i2=="3":
            value1=randint(1,4)
            value2=randint(1,4)
            value3=randint(1,4)
            print(value1,value2,value3)
            roll_again = input("roll again?")
        if i2=="4":
            value1=randint(1,4)
            value2=randint(1,4)
            value3=randint(1,4)
            value4=randint(1,4)
            print(value1,value2,value3,value4)
            roll_again = input("roll again?")
```

I am continuing to add other dice types. Basically I want to be able to type 100 as input and it gives me 100 randint without having to manually code up to if i2=="100" but still maintain the different "ifs". I would also like to print the sum of the values rolled

For the second part, I attempted print(sum(value1,value2)) but since value1 and value2 are not integers I get errors

Comment: Maybe try `random.choices(range(1,i1+1), i2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you want to simplify the operation of your algorithm.

My code works as follows.

The user enters the type of dice (e.g., "d6", "d10") and the number of throws.
The programme checks that the dice type entered is correct (starts with "d" and the number of dice faces is positive).

If the data is correct, the program generates the given number of throws with the given dice, saves the results to the values list and prints them.

The program calculates the sum of the obtained results and prints it.

The program asks the user if they wish to continue with another throw.

If the user decides to have another throw, the program repeats the process of generating and printing the results.

If the user enters incorrect data (e.g., wrong dice format or number of throws less than 1), the program prints an error message.

I assume you will modify this code to suit your needs

```
from random import randint

i1 = input("Enter the type of dice (e.g., d6, d4): ")
i2 = int(input("Enter the number of dice rolls: "))

if i1.startswith("d") and i2 > 0:
    dice_type = int(i1[1:])
    values = []

    for _ in range(i2):
        values.append(randint(1, dice_type))

    print(*values)
    print("Sum:", sum(values))
    roll_again = input("Roll again? (yes/no): ").lower()

    while roll_again == "yes":
        values = []

        for _ in range(i2):
            values.append(randint(1, dice_type))

        print(*values)
        print("Sum:", sum(values))
        roll_again = input("Roll again? (yes/no): ").lower()

else:
    print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid dice type and number of rolls.")
```

Comment: Why did you put the while-loop there? If you just move it up (and set a default `roll_again` like in OP's code), you avoid repeating all the logic.

Comment: Beside the point, but for good design, `i1.startswith("d")` and `i2 > 0` should be *guards* so that you save a level of indentation, and they should be *independent* so that the user knows which part they messed up. E.g. `if not i1.startswith("d"): print("Invalid input. Die type must start with d."); sys.exit(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking for d4, d6, etc, just ask how many sides.

```
sides = int(input("how many sides does each die have?"))
rolls = int(input("how many times to roll the dice?"))
values = [randint(1, sides) for _ in range(rolls)]
print(values)
```